# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getLogger' on apt-get

Tags: apt, python

Every time I run apt-get install  this error occurs. I'm not sure what would have prompted it, except maybe that I installed a new version of python3. The full trace is:

```
Setting up apt-xapian-index (0.46ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 36, in <module>
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getLogger'
dpkg: error processing package apt-xapian-index (--configure):
```

Comment: How did you install a new version of Python 3?

Comment: I added deadsnakes:

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install python3.5`

Comment: What does `python --version` return?

Comment: 2.7.10 @ChaiT.Rex